# How do I properly overload the C# Item property in an interface for COM?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I'm trying to write a class in C# that supports the Item operators in VB6 (`obj("Name")` and `obj!Name`) through COM. I'm using a public class with a corresponding interface.

I have successfully overloaded the square bracket operators in C# and I can call the getter function with the proper operators from VB6, but I'm having trouble with calling the setter function. The error I usually get is "Object doesn't support this property or method".

###### Here's where it get's tricky:

When I **don't** define the interface and use the default COM object that is generated from my class, I can successfully use *both* the getter and setter functions, along with all of my other public functions in the class. However, there is a serious performance degradation in the getter function (about 5x) when I do this, and that is something that I can't live with for this project.

I've looked into early/late binding, and I'm guessing this has something to do with it, but I don't know enough to figure out what is actually going on.

Can anyone explain this for me?

---

Here's my C# class and interface:

```cs
public interface IExampleClass
{
    bool Property1 { get; }

    void Update();
    void SetValue(string name, dynamic value)
    
    dynamic this[string name] { get; set; }
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ExampleClass : IExampleClass
{
    private CustomObject obj;

    public ExampleClass()
    {
        this.obj = new CustomObject(); // This has data when initialized
    }

    public bool Property1 => obj.Property1;

    public void Update() => obj.Update();
    public void SetValue(string name, dynamic value) => obj.SetValue(name, value);

    public dynamic this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
             dynamic item = obj.GetValue(name);
             // do something with item
             return item;
        }
        set { obj.SetValue(name, value); }
    }
}
```

And my VB6 test script:

```vb
Sub TestItemProperty()
    Dim obj As ExampleClass
    Set obj = New ExampleClass
    
    'Test getter function
    MsgBox obj!Name               'This works
    MsgBox obj("Name")            'This works

    'Test setting
    obj.SetValue "Name", "John"   'This works

    'Test setter function
    obj!Name = "John"             'This doesn't work
    obj("Name") = "John"          'This doesn't work
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a (dumb) limitation of the type library exporter. When it sees "object" (or "dynamic" which is the same here) in the interface definition, it will generate a propputref to the tlb property instead of a simple propput https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/28w1w83f(v=vs.100)#properties if you change the type to string for example, it will work fine.

Comment: This is also mentioned here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a753ac81-65c5-4f6a-8d36-adccac5f5d55/com-interop-and-propputpropputref?forum=clr so you must 1) change your interface design or 2) export the tlb as and idl, tweak the idl and rebuild the tlb, or 3) design the interface in idl, build a tlb and use that in C# and VB

Comment: @SimonMourier Very interesting, but that worked for me. Between oleview and midl I was able to automate option 2 and it's working now. I just change propputref on that property to propput and I don't get any more errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but* that worked for me"? It was supposed to work

Comment: @SimonMourier I was confused as to why the exporter had this limitation, _but_, regardless of my confusion, the solution you proposed still worked.